# How to Implement SQL Server Always Encrypted with "ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" and Azure KeyVault in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that uses Entity Framework 6 and targets .NET Framework 4.7.2. I want to implement SQL Server Always Encrypted using the "ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" provider, which utilizes Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and integrate it with Azure KeyVault for secure key management.

I'd like to know the step-by-step process to achieve this. Specifically, I need guidance on how to configure the "ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" provider, set up Azure KeyVault, and update my application code to work seamlessly with Always Encrypted.

Any help or pointers to resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried installing the Provider and followed the instructions as documented here at https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework6PowerTools/blob/community/src/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer/readme.md. I am unable to find hot to configure the KeyVault in this web application.

Comment: Configuring Azure Keyvault is a Server side operation, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-tutorial-getting-started?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms

Comment: @ErikEJ  I have already configured AlwaysEncrypt using the Azure KeyVault on the database side. My doubt is regarding how do I setup my web application and EntityFrameWork to obtain access token/keys from KeyVault and interact with the database?

Comment: Let me google it for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-key-vault-example?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully configured and obtained an encrypted secret value from Azure Key Vault within my ASP.NET web application, which utilizes Entity Framework 6 in combination with the "ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" provider for Always Encrypted integration.

**Step 1: Set Up Azure Key Vault**

- Create an Azure Key Vault in the Azure Portal
- Add a new key (column encryption key) to the Key Vault, which will be used to protect your sensitive data.
- Configure permissions in Azure Key Vault to allow your web application to access the key. Assign the necessary access policy

**Step 2: Update NuGet Packages**
In your  project, make sure you have the following NuGet packages installed:

- `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`
- `EntityFramework` (EF6)
- `ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer`

**Step 3: Update Entity Framework  and  Connection String Configuration**
In your `web.config`

Configure Entity Framework to use the "ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" Provider:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" type="ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Update your connection string  to use the Key Vault secret for the database connection.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDbContext" 
       connectionString="Server=myserver.database.windows.net;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=YourSecretFromKeyVault;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Replace `"YourSecretFromKeyVault"` with the secret name that you stored in Azure Key Vault.

**Step 4: Configure Always Encrypted in Entity Framework**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer;

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasColumnEncryptionKey("YourColumnEncryptionKey", SqlColumnEncryptionCspProvider.ProviderName);
    }
}
```

Replace `"YourColumnEncryptionKey"` with the name of the column encryption key you have created in SQL Server.

**Step 5: Create a Helper for Key Vault Access**
Create a helper class to access secrets from Azure Key Vault

```
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System;

public class KeyVaultHelper
{
    private static readonly string KeyVaultEndpoint = "https://your-keyvault-name.vault.azure.net/";
    private static readonly KeyVaultClient KeyVaultClient;

    static KeyVaultHelper()
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        KeyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    }

    public static string GetSecret(string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            var secretBundle = KeyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(KeyVaultEndpoint, secretName).Result;
            var secretValue = secretBundle.Value;

            // Print the retrieved secret to the console
            Console.WriteLine($"Key Vault Secret": {secretValue}");

            return secretValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error retrieving secret: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]